# Slow network is detected. Fallback font will be used while loading: ../VAADIN/themes/valo/fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff

Tags: java, vaadin

Is there any way to resolve this warning?

I have tried to check various other StackOverflow solutions but those are not working!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a system font instead, which doesn't require a download. To do that, set the `$valo-font-family` variable in your custom theme.

https://vaadin.com/api/valo/#variable-v-font-family